# Hive - Generate sequence or missing data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table (key, value) with key between `0000` and `9999` but it contains holes and duplicate of key. 
Ex: `(0001,3),(0003,2), (0001,6), ...`

What I want is a table (key, MAX(value)) (typically group by key) but with no hole in it (generating the missing keys). 
Ex: `(0000, 0), (0001, 6), (0002, 0), (0003, 2), ...`

Is there any way of doing this with Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the following way:

1. Create a table with a single column containing the values 0000 to 9999 without gaps. You could do this by creating generating the file locally from a script and uploading it to HDFS since the data will be small. If you had a large number of IDs, this could be done as a Map Reduce job.
2. Produce the Max of the existing IDs from your existing Key, Value table e.g. `Select Key, Max(Val) from table Group By Key`
3. Do a left outer join between your list of IDs created in step 1, and your aggregated key value pairs from step 2.
4. Any gaps from the original table will have a Null value against their key as a result of the Left Outer Join. Replace these with 0.

Comment: Thanks. Generate the serie. Then, put it in the DFS and make it an hive table. Of course !